# Using regex to filter out guid's in string

Tags: regex, vb.net, guid

I'm using a certain regex to know where there a certain string values in a string:

Regex: `C\[([A-Z][0-9])\]`
String: `=C[C3]+(C[C3]-C[C5])*(C[C3]-(C[C5]+C[C3]))`

This gets every `C[blabla]` value out of that string and when I ask for group(1), I don't even have to cut of the "`C[`" at the start and the "`]`" at the end.

Now I want to do this but instead of using the `C[]` placeholder, I'm using `G[]` and so not a "`C3`" like string in that placeholder, but a guid so I get these:

Regex: `G\[[{|\(]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[\)|}]?\]`
String: `=Guid[92716d13-01d1-447b-be3f-c090fed6336c]+Guid[92716d13-01d1-447b-be3f-c090fed6336c]`

When I check the regex, it matches a guid perfectly, but I don't get any matches when I use more than just one guid (or when I add characters before or after). I left out the "^$" so it doesn't define a start and end anymore, but that didn't seem to be the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What language is used? Can you show the code where you use your regex?

Comment: I don't even require code, I use a site first to check the regex: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your website.

I put :

```
Guid\[[{|\(]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[\)|}]?\]
```

as a regex

And :

```
Guid[92716d13-01d1-447b-be3f-c090fed6336c]+Guid[92716d13-01d1-447b-be3f-c090fed6336d]
```

in *Input 1*.

I get 2 results in Groups[0] :

```
Guid[92716d13-01d1-447b-be3f-c090fed6336c]
```

and

```
Guid[92716d13-01d1-447b-be3f-c090fed6336d]
```

Comment: Anyway I can get the value between the [ ]?

Comment: Using this regex `[{|\(]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[\)|}]?` you will get only the value between brackets if it's what you want.

Comment: that gives another problem, I can only take the ones between the Guid[ ] placeholders, so with this adjusted regex all guids will be taken, also the ones not in the placeholders.

Comment: I understand so with this one `Guid\[([{|\(]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[\)|}]?)\]` you have the results in Groups[1]

Comment: So... the last one is what you want?

Comment: I guess so, I've gotten an emergency task, need to check it, but will do so when i can

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify the language you are using i made a solution in Java:

```
String regex = "Guid\\[([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12})\\]";
String input = "=Guid[92716d13-01d1-447b-be3f-c090fed6336c]+Guid[92716d13-01d1-447b-be3f-c090fed6336c]";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Prints:

```
92716d13-01d1-447b-be3f-c090fed6336c
92716d13-01d1-447b-be3f-c090fed6336c
```